# Bypass HTTPS implementation of reverse proxy server for any absolute urls in site content

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, reverse-proxy, f5

I have a **reverse proxy server** F5 standing in **front of Apache web server** which hosts my application - http://example.net/documents/.

F5 which is my organization reverse proxy server is out of my reach as it is managed by admins and they recently implemented HTTPS for my site which changed my site from **HTTP to HTTPS**.

All worked good except that my entire site content also got changed to HTTPS including any **absolute HTTP external url references which were part of site content  also got changed to HTTPS**. So, my biggest concern now is to preserve original protocol of my site content(specifically, the external link references like jquery etc. under my site content).

I am confused as to how I can address this as reverse proxy server is not in my reach. **Is there anything that can be done on Apache web-server to preserve original protocol of any absolute urls by bypassing reverse proxy server's HTTPS implementation?** I am not an expert on this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First: You of course should always use https for everything. If you site is accessible through https (through the F5) and you reference js files through http:// many browsers will throw warning about mixed and insecure content. Especially jquery and all other JavaScript modules should perfectly be available through https, so i dont really see an issue here?

Second, no, you wont be able to bypass the content rewrite of the F5 Loadbalancer; You could of course hack something that dynamically concats the urls through javascript or something like that, but that is hacky und subject to fail.

Maybe i could help you better if you give an actual example on where you got a problem with https?